# hystrix @EnableCircuitBreaker in a non spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple spring project based on application context xml files (non spring boot).
How do I use EnableCircuitBreaker for my client in order to use the hystrix command for fallback in my RestTemplate.

Comment: try Spring retry.http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html

Comment: @pvpkiran thanks for the tip. But the problem with retry is that the recover method is based on an exception whereas I need a fallback which will be different for each of my methods depending on the return type.

Comment: You could try Failsafe https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe

Answer (score 2):

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
```

is part of Spring cloud project. which looks for certain classes/methods for some Annotations to do some setup. But You can use Netflix hystrix without using spring cloud(spring boot) at all.

You need to extendd `HystrixCommand` class where ever you want to provide circuitbreaker functionality.
Check out their github page. It has lot of details.
https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: After some searching I found this which is an implementation of netflix hystrix but without writing a lot of code . https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica. the problem with extending HystrixCommand is that for each method you need a class as its run method is implemented once per class. But I multiple methods per class and their implementation is not the same so I need multiple failback methods as well.

Comment: ya. this gives you annotation support.

Comment: if you can control that class which your class is already extending, then move that to an interface and implement that

Answer (score 0):

Adding dependency worked for me

```
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-hystrix', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'
```