# Use @hystrixCommand on lazily initialized classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I have a class which is to be instantiated lazily.

I need to have @hystrixCommand annotation on some methods of this class.

The problem is that @hystrixCommand isn't working on classes not having either @Service or @Component annotation, and @Service and @Component always eagerly load the class.

How to use @hystrixCommand on lazy loaded classes or even in general on the classes without @Services or @Component annotations. Also the class I am referring to is already extending some other class so the solution provided [hystrix @EnableCircuitBreaker in a non spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655063/hystrix-enablecircuitbreaker-in-a-non-spring-boot-application) would not work for me .

Comment: this class which your class extends is it a third party class or a class in your project?

Comment: it is a third part class